# Connection Must be valid and open for saving to MySql

Tags: c#, mysql

My classmates says that I do have lots of connections, but I tried deleting and add some connections but nothing works. I always get "connection must be valid and open" or "connection is already open" and "fatal error encountered during command execution", I hope you guys can help me.

This is my saving part, I put it on the `transact_button`, so after the cashier calculates the item, the information must be on the `mysql` database so I could create a crystal report.

```
        try
        {
        string id = products_lv.SelectedItems[0].Text;
        string name = products_lv.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
        string price = products_lv.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text;
        string qty = products_lv.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[4].Text;



            sql_connect.Close();
            sql_connect.Open();
            sql_command = new MySqlCommand("insert into transaction_cashier(orderid,productid,productname,price,quantity,total,vat,subitems,payment,change) values (@orderid,@produtid,@productname,@price,@quantity,@total,@vat,@subitems,@payment,@change)");
            sql_command.ExecuteReader();
            sql_connect.Close();
            sql_connect.Open();
            sql_command.Connection = sql_connect;
            sql_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderid", id_num.Text);
            sql_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productid", id.ToString());
            sql_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productname", name.ToString());
            sql_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", price.ToString());
            sql_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", qty.ToString());
            sql_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vat", vat_txt.Text);
            sql_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subitems", subitems_txt.Text);
            sql_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment", payment_txt.Text);
            sql_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@change", change_txt.Text);
            sql_connect.Open();
            sql_command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sql_connect.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Saved");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Transaction cashier error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Hope you guys can help me and thanks a lot.

Comment: You really do have so many connections, try opening it once, and close it once in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You have an open connection but you never associate it with your command.  The command has to have a connection to execute over.  When you create the command, you must either pass the connection to the constructor or else set the `Connection` property.

Your code is ridiculous as it is.  Here's the sequence of events:

1. Create the connection.
2. Create the command and associate it with the connection.
3. Add the parameters to the command.
4. Open the connection.
5. Execute the command.
6. Close the connection.

You should use a `using` statement to create the connection and then it will be automatically closed at the end of the block when it's disposed, e.g.

```
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection("connection string here"))
using (var command = new MySqlCommand("SQL code here", connection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParamName", paramValue);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```